# An introductory reference for tensor networks

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, braided-tensor-categories, quantum-computation, tensor-calculus

I found a good reference on Tensor Networks: https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.10049. But I need an introductory reference with detailed proofs on Tensor Networks. Do you know another reference?

Answer (score 4):

Would go to https://tensornetwork.org/ as the first stop. Then I would check out these lectures https://itensor.org/miles/BrazilLectures/TNAndApplications01.pdf.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the links.

Comment: I believe in the natural numbers and I believe the large catdinals are natural too!